# Get values from multiple arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

This is my array which is coming from a `foreach` loop:

```
Array
(
    [count] => 1
    [0] => Array
        (
            [distinguishedname] => Array
                (
                    [count] => 1
                    [0] => CN=Administratie,OU=Test,DC=stefan,DC=nl
                )

            [0] => distinguishedname
            [count] => 1
            [dn] => CN=Administratie,OU=Test,DC=stefan,DC=nl
        )

)
Array
(
    [count] => 1
    [0] => Array
        (
            [distinguishedname] => Array
                (
                    [count] => 1
                    [0] => CN=Anderemailgroep,OU=Test,DC=stefan,DC=nl
                )

            [0] => distinguishedname
            [count] => 1
            [dn] => CN=Anderemailgroep,OU=Test,DC=stefan,DC=nl
        )

)
Array
(
    [count] => 1
    [0] => Array
        (
            [distinguishedname] => Array
                (
                    [count] => 1
                    [0] => CN=Beheergroep,OU=Test,DC=stefan,DC=nl
                )

            [0] => distinguishedname
            [count] => 1
            [dn] => CN=Beheergroep,OU=Test,DC=stefan,DC=nl
        )

)
Array
(
    [count] => 1
    [0] => Array
        (
            [distinguishedname] => Array
                (
                    [count] => 1
                    [0] => CN=Belangrijke Groep,OU=Test,DC=stefan,DC=nl
                )

            [0] => distinguishedname
            [count] => 1
            [dn] => CN=Belangrijke Groep,OU=Test,DC=stefan,DC=nl
        )

)
Array
(
    [count] => 1
    [0] => Array
        (
            [distinguishedname] => Array
                (
                    [count] => 1
                    [0] => CN=Hoofdgroep,OU=Test,DC=stefan,DC=nl
                )

            [0] => distinguishedname
            [count] => 1
            [dn] => CN=Hoofdgroep,OU=Test,DC=stefan,DC=nl
        )

)
Array
(
    [count] => 1
    [0] => Array
        (
            [distinguishedname] => Array
                (
                    [count] => 1
                    [0] => CN=Mailgroep,OU=Test,DC=stefan,DC=nl
                )

            [0] => distinguishedname
            [count] => 1
            [dn] => CN=Mailgroep,OU=Test,DC=stefan,DC=nl
        )

)
Array
(
    [count] => 1
    [0] => Array
        (
            [distinguishedname] => Array
                (
                    [count] => 1
                    [0] => CN=Testgroep2,OU=Test,DC=stefan,DC=nl
                )

            [0] => distinguishedname
            [count] => 1
            [dn] => CN=Testgroep2,OU=Test,DC=stefan,DC=nl
        )

)
```

The question is, how do I get all the CN=**"GroupName"** values from all the arrays in a list or something? It only needs to grab that value from every single array and display it in a list.

For example:

I only want this value from every array.

[image]

And the output should be like this:

```
Administratie
Anderemailgroep
Beheergroep
Belangrijke Groep
Hoofdgroep
Mailgroep
Testgroep2
```

**EDIT**

The array is coming from this piece of code:

```
$result = $adldap->user()->groups('test.user');

            for ($i=0;$i<count($result);$i++) {
            sort($result);
            }
            print_r($result);

    foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
    $check = $adldap->group()->info($value, array(
        'distinguishedname'
    ));

        if (strpos($check[0]['distinguishedname'][0], 'OU=Test') !== false) {
            unset($result[$key]);
            print_r($check);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is that a single array ?

Comment: You should really start to think a little bit more by yourself.. Considdering this is your 3th post and it's always after another piece of code you were provided by..

Comment: We're missing information. No code example provided... The thing itself can be done quite easily...

Comment: Where did you get this array from? Please post the code for that for better understanding. The question is not very clear. Please reframe it.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say your array is **$arrs** which contains of your array values given.
You can do like this.

```
<?php

foreach($arrs as $arr) {
   foreach($arr as $ar) {
       $sep = explode(',',$ar['dn']);
       echo explode('=',$sep[0])[1];
   }
}

?>
```